# Change Spinner's getAdapter() and setAdapter() method

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner, android-adapter

This question seems obvious, but I can't figure it out.
I have a custom LanguageSpinner class:

```
class LanguageSpinner(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : AppCompatSpinner(context, attrs) {

    override fun getSelectedItem(): LanguageSpinnerItem {
        return super.getSelectedItem() as LanguageSpinnerItem
    }

    fun getSelectedLanguage() : Language {
        return selectedItem.language
    }
    
    override fun setAdapter(languageSpinnerAdapter: LanguageSpinnerAdapter) {
        this.adapter = languageSpinnerAdapter // ?
    }

    override fun getAdapter(): LanguageSpinnerAdapter {
        return super.getAdapter() // ?
    }
     
}
```

I need to ensure, that the `getSelectedItem()` method will return a Language class object. So my adapter has to be an instance of `LanguageSpinnerAdapter`. How can I override getter and setter for the adapter to receive instances of this exact custom adapter? As for now, it says that setter overrides nothing. And I understand, it's due to the fact that LanguageSpinnerAdapter is not SpinnerAdapter, but I've implemented it in my custom adapter. So what can I do?
My custom adapter class:

```
class LanguageSpinnerAdapter(
    context: Context, private val languageItems : ArrayList<LanguageSpinnerItem>
    ) : ArrayAdapter<LanguageSpinnerItem>(context, R.layout.spinner_item, languageItems),
    SpinnerAdapter {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok so you have the following classes: LanguageSpinner, LanguageSpinnerItem, Language, LanguageSpinnerAdapter and a custom Adapter. Is that correct? I have also not understood what you want to achieve with you spinner. Please make that clear in your question.

Comment: @BierDav There are only 3 classes that matter in this question: LanguageSpinner, LanguageSpinnerItem, LanguageSpinnerAdapter. I want to ensure that `getAdapter` will always return `LanguageSpinnerAdapter` and `setAdapter` will receive only `LanguageSpinnerAdapter` as a parameter. This is it.

Comment: doesn't this simply do the job `if(languageSpinnerAdapter is LanguageSpinnerAdapter)`. If you want to you can throw a exception. Of course the far more beautiful solution would be to use the `as?` operator and then use the `?:` operator to throw an exception. Other wise don't throw a exception after the elvis operator. Instead use a simple return statement

Comment: @BierDav Thank you! I thought about this solution, but is there any way to implement it as described in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
class LanguageSpinner(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : AppCompatSpinner(context, attrs) {
    override fun setAdapter(languageSpinnerAdapter: SpinnerAdapter) {
        super.setAdapter((languageSpinnerAdapter as? LanguageSpinnerAdapter) ?: return)
    }

    override fun getAdapter(): SpinnerAdapter? {
        return super.getAdapter() as? LanguageSpinnerAdapter
    }
}
```

I prefer this way of doing null safety but there are also people using let

```
(languageSpinnerAdapter as? LanguageSpinnerAdapter)?.let {
    super.setAdapter(it)
}
```

By the way you have to use SpinningAdapter otherwise you will not match the base method. That results in a 'method overrides nothing' error.